# a href link on img is not working

Tags: html, css

Hi I have the following code that have few links to images,but its not showing the link also it not redirecting to the page.yes i put about us in correct directory like as my menu

```
my menu

<li><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="team.html">Team</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="about_us.html"><img class="ls-s2"  src="images/slides/xichlofrontvideo.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 60px; slidedirection : bottom; slideoutdirection : bottom;  durationin : 1000; durationout : 750; easingin : easeInOutQuint; easingout : easeInBack; delayin : 500; delayout : 0; showuntil : 0; "></a>
<a href="about_us.html"><img class="ls-s2"  src="images/slides/cap_a1.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 160px; left: 600px; slidedirection : top; slideoutdirection : top;  durationin : 2000; durationout : 750; easingin : easeInOutQuint; easingout : easeInBack; delayin : 500; delayout : 0; showuntil : 0; "></a>
<a href="about_us.html"><img class="ls-s2"  src="images/slides/cap_a2.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 290px; left: 600px; slidedirection : right; slideoutdirection : right;  durationin : 2500; durationout : 750; easingin : easeInOutQuint; easingout : easeInBack; delayin : 500; delayout : 0; showuntil : 0; "></a>
<a href="about_us.html"><img class="ls-s2"  src="images/slides/cap_a3.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 410px; left: 600px; slidedirection : bottom; slideoutdirection : bottom;  durationin : 3000; durationout : 750; easingin : easeInOutQuint; easingout : easeInBack; delayin : 500; delayout : 0; showuntil : 0; "></a>
<a href="about_us.html"><img class="ls-s2"  src="images/slides/cap_a3.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 410px; left: 750px; slidedirection : bottom; slideoutdirection : bottom;  durationin : 3500; durationout : 750; easingin : easeInOutQuint; easingout : easeInBack; delayin : 500; delayout : 0; showuntil : 0; "></a>
```

Comment: `"but its not working"` is not an accurate enough description. Please elaborate more.

Comment: Your image tags are not closed?

Answer (score 4):

Check if your "about_us.html" file is in the right directory. If it's not redirecting it is probably not in the right directory.

You are using `href="about_us.html"` which means that the "about_us.html" file has to be in the same directory like the file in which you have the `a` tag placed.

You maybe should have a look at relative and absolute URLs. This may help you:

- http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html
- [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)
- http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/relative_and_absolute_urls.php3

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible that your image is behind the bar. For that you can use the z-index property.
Use this:

```
a {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your code file in the same directory with the `about_us.html`? If not, modify it.

So does the `images/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ej4ac/

What is not working ?

Cant be redirect ?

```
<a href="about_us.html"><img class="ls-s2"  src="images/slides/xichlofrontvideo.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 60px; slidedirection : bottom; slideoutdirection : bottom;  durationin : 1000; durationout : 750; easingin : easeInOutQuint; easingout : easeInBack; delayin : 500; delayout : 0; showuntil : 0; "></a>
            <a href="about_us.html"><img class="ls-s2"  src="images/slides/cap_a1.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 160px; left: 600px; slidedirection : top; slideoutdirection : top;  durationin : 2000; durationout : 750; easingin : easeInOutQuint; easingout : easeInBack; delayin : 500; delayout : 0; showuntil : 0; "></a>
            <a href="about_us.html"><img class="ls-s2"  src="images/slides/cap_a2.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 290px; left: 600px; slidedirection : right; slideoutdirection : right;  durationin : 2500; durationout : 750; easingin : easeInOutQuint; easingout : easeInBack; delayin : 500; delayout : 0; showuntil : 0; "></a>
            <a href="about_us.html"><img class="ls-s2"  src="images/slides/cap_a3.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 410px; left: 600px; slidedirection : bottom; slideoutdirection : bottom;  durationin : 3000; durationout : 750; easingin : easeInOutQuint; easingout : easeInBack; delayin : 500; delayout : 0; showuntil : 0; "></a>
            <a href="about_us.html"><img class="ls-s2"  src="images/slides/cap_a3.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 410px; left: 750px; slidedirection : bottom; slideoutdirection : bottom;  durationin : 3500; durationout : 750; easingin : easeInOutQuint; easingout : easeInBack; delayin : 500; delayout : 0; showuntil : 0; "></a>
```

I guess your about_us.html is not in the correct directory path because according to the above jsfiddle, ur codes works well and a href is working.

Comment: @Xavi did you put your about_us.html in the correct directory path ?

Comment: @Xavi not sure what's the problem ur facing, you can still find the solution at http://jsfiddle.net/ej4ac/4/ I think you should try target="_blank".

Answer (score 0):

try to insert / in the href tag before the URL like this : `<a href="/about_us.html"></a>`